# I need to find a string in a string then replace that and text around it

Tags: php, string, replace, strpos

i have a string that has markers and I need to replace with text from a database. this text string is stored in a database and the markers are for auto fill with data from a different part of the database.

```
$text = '<span data-field="la_lname" data-table="user_properties">
{Listing Agent Last Name}
</span>
<br>RE: The new offer<br>Please find attached....'
```

if i can find the data marker by:
`strpos($text, 'la_lname');`
can i use that to select everything in and between the `<span>` and `</span>` tags..

so the new string looks like:

```
'Sommers<br>RE: The new offer<br>Please find attached....'
```

I thought I could explode the string based on the `<span>` tags but that opens up a lot of problems as I need to keep the text intact and formated as it is. I just want to insert the data and leave everything else untouched.

Comment: Please be more specific: How do you (want to) translate the given span to the Agents name "Sommers"? Where does this information come from? Why didn't you just print out the name right away? Are you able to modify the given Span-Output?

Comment: the la_lname comes from a list of last names in a database. The template text comes from the database and then we go through and make a copy for each name with the name inserted in the placeholder

Comment: Possible duplciate of: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what's between two parts of a string
for example if you have

```
<span>SomeText</span>
```

If you want to get **SomeText** then I suggest using a function that gets whatever is between two parts that you put as parameters

```
<?php
function getbetween($content,$start,$end) {
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}
return '';
} 

$text = '<span>SomeText</span>';
$start = '<span>';
$end = '</span>';
$required_text = getbetween($text,$start,$end);
$full_line = $start.$required_text.$end;
$text = str_replace($full_line, 'WHAT TO REPLACE IT WITH HERE',$text);
```

Comment: ok, i see how this works but how do i find the <span tag just before the start of the keyword as in my example? I will have multiple <span> placeholders

Comment: You need to add something unique to it.. for example make it <span id="get_text">.. only the start has to be unique.. the end will be the closest one to the start.

Comment: ok i can make that work... how do i replace the entire line INCLUDING the span? <span>...</span> becomes sommers

Comment: I edited my answer to include that so you can replace the entire line including the spans and what's between them

Answer (score 0):

You could try [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or use a [DOM Parser](http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php), which is far more useful for navigating HTML-like-structure.

I should add that while *regular expressions* should work just fine in this example, you may need to do more complex things in the future or traverse more intrincate DOM structures for your replacements, so a DOM Parser is the way to go in this case.

Comment: i see getelementsbytag name but i am not seeing where i can maybe select by data-sometype and then replace the tags and the innerhtml with some other text

Comment: @SmithSmithy: With an xpath query.

Answer (score 0):

Using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = str_get_html('<span data-field="la_lname" data-table="user_properties">{Listing Agent Last Name}</span><br>RE: The new offer<br>Please find attached....');
$html->find('span')->innerText = 'New value of span';
```

Comment: I like this... so can i find {specific text} and replace it with {new text} the brackets are required.